# How does Visual Studio know that I changed the makefile?

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

I have a Visual C++ 2008 project where I first generate the project's files from a makefile using CMake. I noticed that when I change the makefile in Notepad++ with Visual Studio open, it automatically includes any new .cpp files I added to reflect the changes during the next build. I would think that I would need to rerun CMake to add the changes into the project but it doesn't seem to be the case.

How does the Visual Studio compiler know that I made any changes in the makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not much rocket science going on here: by looking at the timestamp of the Makefile's last modification. :-) Pretty much the same way make figures out what target is out-of-date...

Comment: Thanks! But how does it know which makefile is associated with the project to check?

Comment: Beats me. Maybe VS is smart enough to check certain make file name patterns? Can you somehow trace what files VS opens (analogue to a Unix strace or ktrace for `open` system calls? That should provide some insight).